# How to change input values using Auth Component?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using the last version of CakePhp.

I developed a simple web form with email and password(i am using email instead of username).

Now i have the follow problem.

I have encrypted email field in the database, so, for this reason, i can not use auth Component as is because it will check plan email and hashed password. I need encrypted email and hashed Password.

So Now,  before login() how can i change the value of the email field?

Thank you

Comment: What encryption algorithm you are using for the email field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AuthComponent` is still suitable in your situation.

If you include the component specifying that the email address is also the 'username'

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
     )
);
```

And then just encrypt the email address before you call the login method.

```
 $this->request->data['User']['email'] = someEncryption($this->request->data['User']['email']);
 $this->Auth->login();
```

Hope this helps

More Info: 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `FormAuthenticate` class or encrypt the email in `$this->request->data` before you call `$this->Auth->login()`.

If you go with the first option, save the unencrypted email in a tmp var and if login fails, restore the unencrypted value so the encrypted value doesn't appear in the form.

For custom authenticate class: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects